# Will this GeForce 9500 GT drive two monitors (expanded desktops)?

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I'd like to power two monitors with this video card, each with its own desktop in Windows (that is: extended, not cloned).

[MSI M452-9502 GeForce 9500 GT Video Card - 512MB DDR2, PCI Express 2.0, DVI, HDMI, VGA - OEM](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?Sku=M452-9502)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the page you linked to:

> **Dual Monitor Ready**
>   This product supports Dual Monitors and has Dual DVI Ports.
>   Dual View technology offers multiple display support on up to two separate monitors. This improves the capabilities and productivity of the user by allowing them to spread multiple windows over two monitors and view them simultaneously. Dual Monitors is one of the simplest, yet most amazing productivity boosters you can add to your PC!

The image shows one DVI, one VGA output and one HDMI port. In this case the HDMI port counts as DVI, though you will need an adaptor for your monitor (unless it has an HDMI input of course). *Thanks to @quack quixote for putting me right on this.*

Therefore, given the right cabling and adaptors you should be able to extend your desktop onto the second monitor without any trouble.

Comment: They don't both have to be DVI.  But you're saying it's safe for me to assume that each of those ports will power its own monitor concurrently?  Maybe this is a dumb question -- haha.  I just assumed I could choose only one of the three ports to use at any given time...

Comment: Oh wow.  I missed the first part of your quoted text above.  I'm sorry.  I had dismissed that entire paragraph (when I first saw it) because of your italicized text.  When *you* quoted it, I took your italics to mean I should, again, dismiss the entire paragraph, which I mistook to be pointing out only Dual DVI (which, clearly, isn't possible).  I see now.  It supports "dual" monitors (not three).  Got it.  Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: they aren't technically wrong; the GPU supports two DVI outputs, and **the HDMI port counts as DVI for this purpose**.  (if you look, you can see the HDMI port on the other side of the VGA port.)  you need an HDMI-to-DVI adapter to plug in a second DVI monitor.

Comment: @quack - Ah, *that* explains it. When I had to replace my system a couple of months ago due to motherboard failure I ended up buying a more expensive graphics card expecting two actual DVI outputs based on a statement like that but getting one VGA, one DVI and one HDMI.